# How can I configure ILogger to output the logs to a specific file?

Tags: logging, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 2 web app I'm deploying to production, and need to enable logs to troubleshoot an error. I can't find anywhere in the docs as to the schema in the logger section of appsettings.json. Here's what I have there:

```json
"Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information" }
    ,"Console": { "IncludeScopes": "true" }
  }
```

When I run the exe from the console, the log info is shown in the console, but entity framework is also logging so I can't see my own messages as the amount of output displayed is limited. Thus I need to output the logs to a file, say C:\temp\my.log. How can I configure ASP.NET Core 2 to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you have to set `stdoutLogEnabled` to `true` and `stdoutLogFile` to some valid folder path in the deployed application's web.config

Comment: I believe you need to add a third party logger to write to files. One of the easiest to add is [Serilog](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore). It has a sink to [write to a file](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40073743/how-to-log-to-a-file-without-using-third-party-logger-in-net-core) seems has the same requirement as yours.

You could also try to use NLog to output the logs to a file. It could also determine the layout of logs in its config file.

After [installing](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2),in startup.cs, set logs folder:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("configDir", "C:\\git\\damienbod\\AspNetCoreNlog\\Logs");
        GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("connectionString", Configuration.GetConnectionString("NLogDb"));

        loggerFactory.AddNLog();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Then in nlog.config,set fileName:

```
 <target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" fileName="${gdc:item=configDir}\nlog-all.log"/>
```

[Here is an example you could refer to](https://github.com/damienbod/AspNetCoreNlog).

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using NLog as you suggested. Can't believe one needs a third party tool for this, I would have thought this was a very common scenario.

Answer (score 6):

> Thus I need to output the logs to a file, say C:\temp\my.log. How can I configure ASP.NET Core 2 to do this?

Serilog has [a package for that](https://www.nuget.org/packages/serilog.extensions.logging.file).

```
dotnet add package Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File
```

We configure it like this.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddLogging();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) 
{
    loggerFactory.AddFile("C:\\temp\\my.log");
}
```

See also: https://nblumhardt.com/2016/10/aspnet-core-file-logger/

Answer (score 1):

The alternative way it's using middleware like in this [RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware.cs](https://gist.github.com/elanderson/c50b2107de8ee2ed856353dfed9168a2) file

Please read comments on gist because code the has some problems. Comments about body seek position are important.

Setting up the web.config param stdout like `stdoutLogEnabled="true"` and `stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
   <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
     <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" 
          modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" 
                arguments=".\ReportViewer.dll" 
                stdoutLogEnabled="true" 
                stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
   </system.webServer>
 </location>
</configuration>
```

And you should create two folders `logs` and   `logs\stdout` in the project directory.