# Logging in .NET Core and ASP.NET Core

Tags: .net-core

I want to log certain output in .net core webapi to a .txt file.

The Microsoft documentation says https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5002040#console

```
 Call WebApplication.CreateBuilder, which adds the following logging providers:
 Console
 Debug
 EventSource
 EventLog: Windows only
```

There is no information on how to write to a .log file or a .txt file. It all says about console, debug and eventlog.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where does the log file get written to in .Net Core Logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57614016/where-does-the-log-file-get-written-to-in-net-core-logging)

Answer (score 0):

In .NET logging has two parts - the `ILoggerFactory` which you inject into your code and use to write the logs, and a logging *provider* which handles the output.

When you call `WebApplication.CreateBuilder` it sets up the 4 output providers provided.

If you also want to log output to a text file you need to add a logging provider that writes text files. You can roll your own `ILoggerProvider` or just use an [existing one](https://github.com/adams85/filelogger/blob/master/source/FileLogger/FileLoggerProvider.cs).

If you add an `ILoggerProvider` that writes files to your DI services that will be used every time a log is written.

Answer (score -3):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(AdminLoginViewModel admin)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    return View();
    
  //AppUser user =await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(admin.UserName);
  AppUser user = await _userManager.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.IsAdmin && x.UserName == admin.UserName);
    
  if (user == null)
  {
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "UserName or Password is not correct!");
    return View();
  }
    
  var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, admin.PassWord, false, false);
    
  if (!result.Succeeded)
  {
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "UserName or Password is not correct!");
    return View();
  }
    
  return RedirectToAction("index", "dashboard");
}
```

layout/

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject UserManager<AppUser> _userManager
@{
  AppUser logged = null;
  if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    logged = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?