How can I change the log format of HTTP logging middleware in .NET 8
I have a requirement for creating Request/Response Logging. I am using default Logger implementation of Microsoft.
//Add Http Logging
builder.Services.AddHttpLogging(options =>
{
    options.CombineLogs = true;

    options.LoggingFields = HttpLoggingFields.RequestQuery | HttpLoggingFields.RequestPath |
        HttpLoggingFields.RequestBody | HttpLoggingFields.ResponseStatusCode | HttpLoggingFields.Duration;
});


//Using Middleware
app.UseHttpLogging();

In my appSettings.json file:
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpLogging.HttpLoggingMiddleware": "Information"
    }
  }

My issue is the default Log format of HTTP logging Middleware. This is what printed on my console:
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpLogging.HttpLoggingMiddleware[9]
      Request and Response:
      PathBase:
      Path: /api/film/rating
      QueryString:
      StatusCode: 200
      RequestBody: {
  "title": "G K Mon",
  "rating": "G"
}
      RequestBodyStatus: [Completed]
      Duration: 1595.698

Can I customize this default log format of HTTP Logging Middleware? Additional question is that how should I store logs in file without using Third party library.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68363461/22971430

HttpLogging has pre-defined format/order and doesn't have a built-in way to change. You could try implement a custom loggerProvider to modify the logmessage before log and then write to a file.
Reformat the logMessage before output.

    public class CustomHttpLogger : ILogger
    {
        private readonly string _filePath;

        public CustomHttpLogger(string filePath)
        {
            _filePath = filePath;
        }
        public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state) => null;

        public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel) => true;

        public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
        {
            var logMessage = formatter(state, exception);
            if (eventId.Name == "RequestResponseLog")
            {
                // Example: Reorder fields manually (string manipulation, regex, etc.)
                string reorderedLogMessage = ReorderLogFields(logMessage);

                // Output the reordered log message ,  if you use console without clearproviders you will find the default provider also logging.
                //Console.WriteLine(reorderedLogMessage);
                File.AppendAllText(_filePath, reorderedLogMessage);
            }
            //else
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine(logMessage);
            //}
        }

        private string ReorderLogFields(string logMessage)
        {
            var messages=logMessage.Split("\r\n");
            string newMessage = "";

            newMessage += messages.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartsWith("QueryString")) + "\r\n";
            newMessage += messages.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartsWith("PathBase"))+ "\r\n";
            newMessage += messages.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartsWith("RequestBody")) + "\r\n";
            newMessage += messages.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartsWith("StatusCode")) + "\r\n";
            newMessage += messages.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartsWith("Duration")) + "\r\n";

            return newMessage; 
        }
    }

Warp this logger to a logger provider
    public class CustomHttpLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
    {
        private readonly string _filePath;

        public CustomHttpLoggerProvider(string filePath)
        {
            _filePath = filePath;
        }
        public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
        {
            return new CustomHttpLogger(_filePath);
        }

        public void Dispose() { }
    }

Then added to logging providers
//This will clear the default providers, then only your custom provider will work.
//builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddProvider(new CustomHttpLoggerProvider("E:\\log1.txt"));
builder.Services.AddHttpLogging(options =>
{
    
    options.CombineLogs = true;

    options.LoggingFields = HttpLoggingFields.RequestQuery | HttpLoggingFields.RequestPath |
        HttpLoggingFields.RequestBody | HttpLoggingFields.ResponseStatusCode | HttpLoggingFields.Duration;
});

Test result

